# Styling a browser generated shadow-root DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

I want to style the input in #shadow-root but it seems it's not possible and I understand that it might not be recommended practice. Nevertheless I have design I need to follow if possible and searching for solutions are either deprecated or using javascript to add :parts, what maybe is for your own generated #shadow-root html and not by browser? Perhaps there is a reasonable way that I'm not seeing?

Adding this:

```
<input type="file" name="resume">
```

Outputs this in chrome:

```
<input type="file" name="resume">
  #shadow-root (user-agent)
    <input type="button" value="Choose file" pseudo="-webkit-file-upload-button" id="file-upload-button">
      #shadow-root (user-agent)
        "Choose file"
    </input>
    <span aria-hidden="true">No file</span>
</input>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button

Comment: have you tried creating a custom userdefined HTML element ?